# Proof that $M_f$ is a ring

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $$S(A,B)=(A\backslash B) \cup (B \backslash A) $$
be the symmetric difference.
Can someone explain how the 1st equality is obtained? 
[image]

This is from a proof in Karen Saxe's book - Beginning functional analysis lemma 3.4 Proving $M_f$ is a ring
Where $M_f$ is the collection of subsets $A \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $D(A_k,A) \rightarrow 0$

Comment: $A\setminus B=A\cap B^{c}$.

Comment: can you tell me what $B^c$ represents?

Comment: It is the complement of $B$, i.e. all elements not in $B$.